# Why does this switch statement return 23 instead of 2?

Tags: c++

I am a bit confused here, the result is 23 but I keep thinking it should be 2, I need help understanding why it's returning 23 instead of 2, thank you!

```
int x = 2; 
switch(x){
  case 1:
    cout << "1";
    break;
  case 2:
    cout << "2";
  case 3:
    cout << "3";
    break;
  default:
    cout << "0";
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `break` in case 2.

Comment: Search switch fallthrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement falls through when there's no break statement at the end of a case.

```
    break;
 case 2:
    cout << "2";  // fallthrough here, even though case 3 is not matched.
  case 3:
    cout << "3";
    break;
```

So actually you are printing the `2`, and then the `3`, which looks like `23`.

This is probably not intentional. If it is, and you can use c++17, you can be explicit about it.

```
    break;
 case 2:
    cout << "2";  
    [[fallthrough]]
  case 3:
    cout << "3";
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, I know it's due to the break statement, but why does the next statement run? Does it not check if x == 3? Thank you!

Comment: No, it doesn't. I wrote it as a comment, but as soon as one case is matched, it's as if all the case labels *disappear*.

Comment: It makes sense now, thank you very much!